# Syncing my full node - only connects to 1 peer

Tags: full-node

So I get the following error while trying to sync my full node:

https://gyazo.com/fb60b6b862f08d95abbe702b85ec6be4

Basically it seems like I'm only connecting to one node, and rejecting all the others, this makes me worried that I'm syncing to the wrong chain. This is my first time running a full node, so I have no experience how to check if this is correct or not.

Edit: I just noticed I'm running v0.11.1.0. Which is not the latest one, no idea how I downloaded that version tbh, but I'm running v0.12.0.0 and I'm syncing smoothly.

Comment: For the record, 0.12.2.0 is out probably sometime tomorrow, and this is the one you will want, as 0.12.0.0 has a sync bug which may wedge sync until you restart.

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, you need to run a v0.12 release (currently 0.12.1.0). So download the current release and sync. As @user3603 mentioned in the comment, 0.12.2.0 will be released very soon. You can still use the current release to sync and then update to 0.12.2.0 when that gets released (or just wait for 12.2).